# How convert sql with count to linq

Tags: sql, linq

How can i convert this to linq?

```
select i.CatName,COUNT(*) as n_items
from ixcxs i
group by i.CatName
```

or lambda expression will be helpful

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to select first item from group to get CatName - use grouping key instead:

```
var query = from i in ixcxs
            group i by i.CatName into g
            select new {
               CatName = g.Key,
               n_items = g.Count()
            };
```

Same with methods syntax:

```
var query = ixcxs.GroupBy(i => i.CatName)
                 .Select(g => new { CatName = g.Key, n_items = g.Count() });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ixcxs.GroupBy(g => g.CatName)
    .Select(s => new 
    {
        CatName = s.Key, 
        n_items = s.Count() 
    });
```

same thing in query syntax:

```
from i in ixcxs
group i by i.CatName into g
select new 
{
    CatName = g.Key,
    n_items = g.Count()
}
```

Comment: The methods 'Single' and 'SingleOrDefault' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Comment: I did it with 
`from t in db.ixcxs
                        group t by new
                        {
                            t.CatName
                        } into g
                        select new
                        {
                            g.Key.CatName,
                            Total = g.Count()
                        };`

but which is more optimal

Comment: Hmmm okay thats another way